# Image archive without date

Tags: media

I don't care about having images catalogued by date, I actually hate the subdirectories it creates by year and by month when you upload an image. Is there a way to store them all in the same folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uncheck this box:

**Setting/Media**

[ ] Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders

Comment: Thanks, how did I miss that?! ;-)